# Word for collecting all the statements into one paragraph

Tags: word-request

Is there a verb for: When one wants to collect all statements one said into a single paragraph?

Context: Suppose you're talking about a thing abc, you said about 10 sentences separately about this thing. Now I want you to "..verb.." (not exactly "collect") all what you said into one paragraph.

Example sentence: "(verb) all the statements you said about abc into a single paragraph"

AFAIK, there is a word for that but I can't think of it now. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ***paraphrasing*** simply means saying the same thing in ***different*** words. If you want to say the same thing in ***less*** words, you're ***summarising***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*[Collate.](https://www.lexico.com/definition/collate)*
Collect and combine (texts, information, or data)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is consolidate. This would also apply if the sentences were in some way being modified to fit together into the paragraph. A consolidated version need not just have copies of the sentences. In the same vein one might amalgamate them.

Another option is aggregate which would also work if they were being modified or just collected together.

If the sentences are just being put together end to end then concatenate is also possible but is a slightly more technical word. It is widely used in some computing scenarios.